# pattern matching R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

ca.df

```
id    Category
1     Noun
2     Negative
3     Positive
4     adj
5     word
```

Each term is assigned to more than 1 category, therefore, it corresponds with more than 1 id. In terms.df all the ids are in one column.

terms.df

```
Terms   id
 Love    1 4 5 3
 Hate    2 4 5
 ice     1 5
```

id in terms is corresponded with category in ca.df. I want an output like this:

x.df

```
Category      terms

Noun          ice Love
Negative      Hate
Positive      Love
adj           Hate Love
word          ice Hate Love
```

How to do this?

Comment: In `terms.df`, shouldn't ids for `Love` be `3 4 5` instead of `1 4 5`?

Comment: should be 1 4 5, thanks!

Comment: Then why in `x.df` the `Positive` category gets any term, since there is no `3` in `terms.df`?

Comment: It is still unclear to me how the output is created. In `terms.cf`, `Love` has `1` among its ids, but it doesn't appear in the `Noun` category (according to the input, output for `Noun` should be `Noun  ice love`, as visible in the answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible `data.table`/`splitstackshape` packages solution

```
library(splitstackshape) ## loads `data.table` package too
terms.df <- cSplit(terms.df, "id", sep = " ", direction = "long")
setkey(terms.df, id)[ca.df, .(Category , Terms = toString(Terms)), by = .EACHI]

#    id Category           Terms
# 1:  1     Noun       Love, ice
# 2:  2 Negative            Hate
# 3:  3 Positive            Love
# 4:  4      adj      Love, Hate
# 5:  5     word Love, Hate, ice
```

---

**Some explanations**

1. We first split the `id` column by spaces according to the `Terms` column
2. Then we are performing a *binary left join* between the two data sets on the `id` column
3. *While joining*, we are concatenating the `Terms` column back according to each join using the `by = .EACHI` operator which allows us to perform different operations while joinig

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `tidyr` and `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
ca.df$id <- as.character(ca.df$id)

terms.df %>% separate(id,into=paste0("V",1:3),sep = " ",extra = "merge") %>%
  gather(var,id,-Terms) %>%
  filter(!is.na(id)) %>%
  left_join(ca.df,by="id") %>%
  select(-var,-id) %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  summarize(Terms=paste(Terms,collapse=" "))
```

Output :

```
Source: local data frame [4 x 2]

      Category         Terms
    1 Negative          Hate
    2     Noun      Love ice
    3      adj     Love Hate
    4     word ice Love Hate
```

Data :

```
ca.df <- read.table(text = 
"id    Category
1     Noun
2     Negative
3     Positive
4     adj
5     word",head=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

terms.df <- read.table(text = 
"Terms   id
Love    '1 4 5'
Hate    '2 4 5'
ice     '1 5'
",head=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` to combine based on *id*

```
ca.df <- data.frame(id=1:5, Category=c("Noun", "Negative", "Positive", "adj", "word"))
terms.df <- data.frame(Terms=c(rep("Love", 3), rep("Hate", 3), rep("ice", 2)), 
        id = c(1,4,5,2,4,5,1,5))
x.df <- merge(ca.df, terms.df, by="id")
x.df

  id Category Terms
1  1     Noun  Love
2  1     Noun   ice
3  2 Negative  Hate
4  4      adj  Love
5  4      adj  Hate
6  5     word  Love
7  5     word  Hate
8  5     word   ice
```

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer but your terms.df doesn't look like mine.

Comment: @Lucia, that's because `x.df` is inconsistent with `terms.df` (see my comments to the question). Since it apparently seems to be unclear how the `x.df` file should be created, could you update the question with the description of what you're trying to do (as opposed to presenting only input and output, as you did)?

Comment: . , thanks for the reply, I've updated the post. Please note that "In terms.df all the ids are in one column"